# Problema na rota ao carregar bundle.js

Tags: react, react-router

Tenho uma rota que possui o carácter barra `"/"` no meio, tal qual mostrado abaixo:

```
<Route path="/answers/:question_id" component={QuestionAnswers}  />
```

O link funciona normal.

```
<Link to={`/questions/${question.id}`}>Answer</Link>
```

Porém, quando mudo o componente ou atualizo a página dá o seguinte erro:

> erro: O recurso de “http://localhost:4000/questions/bundle.js” foi bloqueado devido ao tipo MIME (“text/html”) não coincidir com (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Como faço para o `js` da aplicação ficar sempre em `/bundle.js` ao invés de `questions/bundle.js`?

Meu `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="E0E0E0"/>

  <title>QAR</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?
     family=Roboto:wght@100;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

`index.tsx` da aplicação:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: Mostre seu `index.html`, provavelmente o problema seja lá

Comment: Mostre seu `index.html` compilado, rode o comando de build e pegue da pasta onde ele é criado

Comment: Não tem como responder! é um erro local, não é pra acontecer isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era na configuração do webpack que estava faltando a propriedade `output.publicPath`:

```js
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin')

const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

module.exports = {
    mode: isDevelopment ? 'development' : 'production',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.tsx'),
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.(js|ts|tsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },

            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    { loader: 'css-loader' },
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                }
            },
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        historyApiFallback: true,
        hot: true,
        port: 4000
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
            }
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html')
        }),
        isDevelopment && new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin()
    ].filter(Boolean)
}
```